# makefile if condition outside rule

Tags: makefile

I have makefile if condition like this outside of rules:

```
ifneq ("$(wildcard ${EXT}/CHECK)","")
    $(info "external binaries exist")
else
    @mkdir -p ${EXT}; \
    cd ${EXT}; \
    scp sam@192.168.10.1:/media/data/external/${BINARY} . ; \
    echo "" > CHECK; \
    cd ..;
endif
```

I am ggeting following error:

```
 *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

at this line: `@mkdir -p ${EXT}; \`

I want to make sure this lines are running before any rule. Because I set some variables based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with if conditions.

Makefiles are not shell scripts.  You can't just write a shell script into a makefile and expect them to be executed.  They are syntax errors, as you've seen, because makefiles are not shell scripts.

Makefiles can *contain* shell scripts, but **only** in the context of a recipe of a rule.

I don't understand why you want to do this outside the context of a rule but the only way to do it is with the `shell` function:

```
_dummy := $(shell mkdir -p ${EXT} && \
    cd ${EXT} && \
    scp sam@192.168.10.1:/media/data/external/${BINARY} . && \
    echo "" > CHECK)
```